# SQL error or missing database (table destination has x columns but y values were supplied)

Tags: sqlite

I have 2 tables "Source" and "Destination" that have the same fields, except for the destination having an extra 'date' field

I need to copy the all the fields to their corresponding fields in destination leaving date blank.

I tried:

```
INSERT INTO Destination SELECT * FROM Source
```

got :

```
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (table destination has 18 columns but 17 values were supplied).
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear - you're trying to insert 17 values into a table with 18 columns and SQL doesn't know what you intend.

You fix that by specifying those columns explicitly, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO Destination(field1, field2, ... field17)
SELECT field1, field2, ... field17
FROM Source;
```